# If I stay 6 months abroad, do I pray qasr salat?

Tags: travelling, salat-al-qasr

I am visiting the UK and am proposed to stay for 6 months. Is praying the qasr salat permissible in my case, or do I have to perform the full prayer?

Comment: This question is rather lacking in details.  What school of fiqh are you interested in?  What if any research effort have you applied to find the answer yourself?  I would strongly recommend you check out the advice in our help centre, particularly the page on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/how-to-ask)" to better understand the Stack Exchange model and the sorts of questions that can expect good answers here.

Comment: Ibadis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibadi would consider you as a mussafir and according their interpretation you could pray qasr. Other schools would say if you settled for at least 4 or 15 days etc.. Note that ibn Taymiyyah to some extent (with conditions) adapted the Ibadi view.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to travel to your destination and remain there for less than 15 days then you must pray the shorten versions of salah as you are considered a musafir (passenger based on Islamic explanation). As you are intending on remaining at your destination for 6 months then you must pray the full salah.

Source: islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/37158

Answer (score 2):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

According to the fatwa of Grand Ayatollah Khamanei, you ought to say your prayers completely (not Qasr) in case that your trip (intention) takes long at least ten days (or more). Then at the mentioned condition as you said “I am visiting the UK and am proposed to stay for 6 months. Is praying the qasr salat permissible in my case, or do I have to perform the full prayer?”. Of course there would be some different detailed matters or remarks concerning the mentioned matter, then you’d better refer to the source to see more complete response about it (if you are familiar with Farsi language).

---

**References:**

- [farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=204)

Comment: @syed shafiuah, of course I assume you'd reached better consequence by mentionign more details at your question. Anyhow, by a general view, it could be considered that you should prayer completely. Good luck.